# Invoking Specific Handler according to Extension

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to Google App Engine and doing Python web app. I want to invoke a specific handler upon extension in url path.

For Example:

If my url is **myapp.appspot.com** then **myapp.appspot.com/(anything ).json** should get handled by JSON handler.

So while registering handler my tuple should look something like this:

**('/*.json', JSONHandler**)

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Yeah accepted. 
Actually i was working with answered code so had late.

Comment: I just noticed that you haven't accepted any.. that's why.. you could go through your old ones as well..

Comment: Yeah i am back here after few months and now understand community better.
Will fix it. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first element in the tuple is a regular expression, so this should work:

```
('/.*\.json', JSONHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but what if i want to implement same and my app url is myapp.appspot.com/directory/anything.json.
I tried above Regx on mentioned but its not working.
Thanks again

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Suppose my url is myapp.appspot.com/directory and i want to invoke JSONHandler on myapp.appspot.com/directory/(anything).json ?

Comment: then use 2 mappings. the first to map your json handler, and the second to map your app. like this [('/directory/.*\.json', JSONHandler), ('/directory', AppHandler)]. suggest you read the docs - it's all explained there http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html